# La animación de texto cambia después de la primera diapositiva

Tags: javascript, jquery

Actualmente tengo un carrusel, en el que hay una transición de varias diapositivas. Tengo una animación inicial, que es perfecta (utilizando el [WOW framework](http://mynameismatthieu.com/WOW/) que para las animaciones). Como es el efecto deseado. Consiste en la aparición de textos, que se ejecutan uno por uno, según el retraso de la biblioteca.

Mi problema consiste en la siguiente diapositiva, el efecto cambia, los textos aparecen por defecto y realizan la animación mientras se muestran los textos. Quiero que en todas las diapositivas, la animación de los textos sea la misma que en la primera diapositiva.

Éste es mi código (también disponible en [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jotasgarcia/72n46nxx/)):

```js
'use strict';

angular.module("demo", ['angular-svg-round-progressbar'])
.controller("mainCtrl", function($scope) {

  $scope.clockwise = true;
  $scope.color="#32db64";
  $scope.current=80;
  $scope.max=100;

  $scope.test = function(currentAmount, options, element){
    var currentVal = parseFloat(Math.round(currentAmount)).toFixed(0);
    $(".valores_progreso").text( currentVal + "%");
  };

  new WOW().init();  //http://mynameismatthieu.com/WOW/  

  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.sliderMain').slick({
      slidesToShow: 1,
      slidesToScroll: 1,
      arrows: false,
      fade: true,

      autoplay: true,
      autoplaySpeed: 7000 //5000
    });

    $('.sliderSidebar').slick({
      slidesToShow: 5,
      slidesToScroll: 1,
      dots: false,
      centerMode: false,
      focusOnSelect: true,
      vertical: true,
      arrows: false
    });

    $('.sliderMain').on('afterChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide) {
      var vid = $(slick.$slides[currentSlide]).find('video');
      if (vid.length > 0) {
        $('.sliderMain').slick('slickPause');
        $(vid).get(0).play();
      }
      //After change set it to block
      $('.contenedor_nombre_proyecto').css("display", "block");
      $('.textos').css("display", "block");

    });

    $('.sliderMain').on('beforeChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide) {
      //Defore change set it to none
      $('.contenedor_nombre_proyecto').css("display", "none");
      $('.textos').css("display", "none");

      $scope.$apply(function() {
        $scope.current = currentSlide === 0 ? 0 : 80;
      });
    });

    var videos = document.getElementsByTagName('video');

    for (var i = 0; i < videos.length; i++) {
      videos[i].addEventListener('ended', myHandler, false);
    }

    function myHandler(e) {
      console.log('Video Complete')
      $('.sliderMain').slick('slickPlay');
    }
  });
})
```

```css
.valores_progreso {
  font-size: 40px;
  height: 5px;
  font-family: 'Roboto-light', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.textos {
  font-size:13px;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

.frase_app_proyecto {
  font-size: 25px;
  height: auto;
  font-family: 'Roboto-light', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.contenedor_prueba {
  position:absolute;
  z-index:99999;
  color:#ffffff;
  left:50%;
  top:20%;
}


.contenedor_nombre_proyecto {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: auto;
  max-width: 40%;
  padding: 12px 0;
  background-color: #333333;
  color: #ffffff;
  -webkit-transform: perspective(100px) rotateX(-2deg);
  -moz-transform: perspective(100px) rotateX(-2deg);
  -ms-transform: perspective(100px) rotateX(-2deg);
  -o-transform: perspective(100px) rotateX(-2deg);
  transform: perspective(100px) rotateX(-2deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: left center;
  -moz-transform: left center;
  -ms-transform: left center;
  -o-transform: left center;
  transform: left center;
  opacity: 0.9; 
}

.tabla_progresos  {border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;width: 80%; height: 410px; max-height: 430px; margin: 0 auto;}
.tabla_progresos td{overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;}
.tabla_progresos th{overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;}
.tabla_progresos .celda_tabla_progresos{text-align:center; position: relative;}

.contenedor_tabla_progresos {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -40%);
  -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -40%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -40%);
  -o-transform: translate(-50%, -40%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -40%);
}

.contenedor_centrado_progreso {
  width: 95%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.progress-clock {
  width: 100%;
  top: 50%; 
  left: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  font-size: 25px;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.8/angular.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-svg-round-progressbar/0.4.4/roundProgress.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/wow/1.1.2/wow.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.css">



<div ng-app="demo" ng-controller="mainCtrl">
  <div id="slideBox">
    <!--Sidebar-->
    <div id="main-image" class="sliderMain">
      <div class="contenedor_carteleria_digital">
        <div class="contenedor_nombre_proyecto">
          <div class="nombre_proyecto_principal">
            <h2 class="textos wow fadeInUp" data-wow-duration="2s" data-wow-delay="0s">titulo</h2>
            <h5 class="textos wow fadeInDown" data-wow-duration="2s" data-wow-delay="1s">subtitulo</h5> <span class="textos wow fadeInDown" data-wow-duration="2s" data-wow-delay="2s">holaa</span>
            <p class="textos wow fadeInLeft" data-wow-duration="2s" data-wow-delay="3s">lorem ipsum dolor sit adem operca</p>
            <p class="textos wow fadeInUp" data-wow-duration="2s" data-wow-delay="4s">dato 1</p>
            <p class="textos wow fadeInDown" data-wow-duration="2s" data-wow-delay="5s">dato 2</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/6768666-1080p-wallpapers.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="contenedor_carteleria_digital">
        <div class="contenedor_nombre_proyecto">
          <div class="nombre_proyecto_principal">
            <h2 class="textos wow fadeInUp" data-wow-duration="2s" data-wow-delay="0s">titulo</h2>
            <h5 class="textos wow fadeInDown" data-wow-duration="2s" data-wow-delay="1s">subtitulo</h5> <span class="textos wow fadeInDown" data-wow-duration="2s" data-wow-delay="2s">holaa</span>
            <p class="textos wow fadeInLeft" data-wow-duration="2s" data-wow-delay="3s">lorem ipsum dolor sit adem operca</p>
            <p class="textos wow fadeInUp" data-wow-duration="2s" data-wow-delay="4s">dato 1</p>
            <p class="textos wow fadeInDown" data-wow-duration="2s" data-wow-delay="5s">dato 2</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.hdbloggers.net/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/Wallpapers-HD-Picture.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="contenedor_carteleria_digital">
        <div class="contenedor_nombre_proyecto">
          <div class="nombre_proyecto_principal">
            <h2 class="textos wow fadeInUp" data-wow-duration="2s" data-wow-delay="0s">titulo</h2>
            <h5 class="textos wow fadeInDown" data-wow-duration="2s" data-wow-delay="1s">subtitulo</h5> <span class="textos wow fadeInDown" data-wow-duration="2s" data-wow-delay="2s">holaa</span>
            <p class="textos wow fadeInLeft" data-wow-duration="2s" data-wow-delay="3s">lorem ipsum dolor sit adem operca</p>
            <p class="textos wow fadeInUp" data-wow-duration="2s" data-wow-delay="4s">dato 1</p>
            <p class="textos wow fadeInDown" data-wow-duration="2s" data-wow-delay="5s">dato 2</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.hdbloggers.net/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/Wallpapers-HD-Picture.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="contenedor_carteleria_digital">
        <div class="contenedor_nombre_proyecto">
          <div class="nombre_proyecto_principal">
            <h2 class="textos wow fadeInUp" data-wow-duration="2s" data-wow-delay="0s">titulo</h2>
            <h5 class="textos wow fadeInDown" data-wow-duration="2s" data-wow-delay="1s">subtitulo</h5> <span class="textos wow fadeInDown" data-wow-duration="2s" data-wow-delay="2s">holaa</span>
            <p class="textos wow fadeInLeft" data-wow-duration="2s" data-wow-delay="3s">lorem ipsum dolor sit adem operca</p>
            <p class="textos wow fadeInUp" data-wow-duration="2s" data-wow-delay="4s">dato 1</p>
            <p class="textos wow fadeInDown" data-wow-duration="2s" data-wow-delay="5s">dato 2</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.hdbloggers.net/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/Wallpapers-HD-Picture.jpg">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--slideBox-->
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Cuando se ejecuta la animación por primera vez, puedes ver que todos los elementos del menú (con la clase `textos`) tienen también la clase `animated`. Y cuando se termina la animación, se le quita esa clase (algo que debe hacer WOW por su cuenta).

Parece que es esa clase la que hace que no se muestren las opciones del mneú (aunque no te sabría decir exactamente cómo). Añadiendo esa clase (con la siguiente línea) dentro del evento `beforeChange`, parece que ya se obtiene el efecto que buscas:

```
$(".textos").addClass("animated");
```

Aquí lo puedes ver funcionando:

```js
'use strict';

angular.module("demo", ['angular-svg-round-progressbar'])
.controller("mainCtrl", function($scope) {

  $scope.clockwise = true;
  $scope.color="#32db64";
  $scope.current=80;
  $scope.max=100;

  $scope.test = function(currentAmount, options, element){
    var currentVal = parseFloat(Math.round(currentAmount)).toFixed(0);
    $(".valores_progreso").text( currentVal + "%");
  };

  new WOW().init();  //http://mynameismatthieu.com/WOW/  

  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.sliderMain').slick({
      slidesToShow: 1,
      slidesToScroll: 1,
      arrows: false,
      fade: true,

      autoplay: true,
      autoplaySpeed: 7000 //5000
    });

    $('.sliderSidebar').slick({
      slidesToShow: 5,
      slidesToScroll: 1,
      dots: false,
      centerMode: false,
      focusOnSelect: true,
      vertical: true,
      arrows: false
    });

    $('.sliderMain').on('afterChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide) {
      var vid = $(slick.$slides[currentSlide]).find('video');
      if (vid.length > 0) {
        $('.sliderMain').slick('slickPause');
        $(vid).get(0).play();
      }
      //After change set it to block
      $('.contenedor_nombre_proyecto').css("display", "block");
      $('.textos').css("display", "block");

    });

    $('.sliderMain').on('beforeChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide) {
      //Defore change set it to none
      $('.contenedor_nombre_proyecto').css("display", "none");
      $('.textos').css("display", "none");
      $(".textos").addClass("animated");

      $scope.$apply(function() {
        $scope.current = currentSlide === 0 ? 0 : 80;
      });
    });

    var videos = document.getElementsByTagName('video');

    for (var i = 0; i < videos.length; i++) {
      videos[i].addEventListener('ended', myHandler, false);
    }

    function myHandler(e) {
      console.log('Video Complete')
      $('.sliderMain').slick('slickPlay');
    }
  });
})
```

```css
.valores_progreso {
  font-size: 40px;
  height: 5px;
  font-family: 'Roboto-light', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.textos {
  font-size:13px;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

.frase_app_proyecto {
  font-size: 25px;
  height: auto;
  font-family: 'Roboto-light', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.contenedor_prueba {
  position:absolute;
  z-index:99999;
  color:#ffffff;
  left:50%;
  top:20%;
}


.contenedor_nombre_proyecto {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: auto;
  max-width: 40%;
  padding: 12px 0;
  background-color: #333333;
  color: #ffffff;
  -webkit-transform: perspective(100px) rotateX(-2deg);
  -moz-transform: perspective(100px) rotateX(-2deg);
  -ms-transform: perspective(100px) rotateX(-2deg);
  -o-transform: perspective(100px) rotateX(-2deg);
  transform: perspective(100px) rotateX(-2deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: left center;
  -moz-transform: left center;
  -ms-transform: left center;
  -o-transform: left center;
  transform: left center;
  opacity: 0.9; 
}

.tabla_progresos  {border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;width: 80%; height: 410px; max-height: 430px; margin: 0 auto;}
.tabla_progresos td{overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;}
.tabla_progresos th{overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;}
.tabla_progresos .celda_tabla_progresos{text-align:center; position: relative;}

.contenedor_tabla_progresos {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -40%);
  -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -40%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -40%);
  -o-transform: translate(-50%, -40%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -40%);
}

.contenedor_centrado_progreso {
  width: 95%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.progress-clock {
  width: 100%;
  top: 50%; 
  left: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  font-size: 25px;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.8/angular.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-svg-round-progressbar/0.4.4/roundProgress.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/wow/1.1.2/wow.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.css">



<div ng-app="demo" ng-controller="mainCtrl">
  <div id="slideBox">
    <!--Sidebar-->
    <div id="main-image" class="sliderMain">
      <div class="contenedor_carteleria_digital">
        <div class="contenedor_nombre_proyecto">
          <div class="nombre_proyecto_principal">
            <h2 class="textos wow fadeInUp" data-wow-duration="2s" data-wow-delay="0s">titulo</h2>
            <h5 class="textos wow fadeInDown" data-wow-duration="2s" data-wow-delay="1s">subtitulo</h5> <span class="textos wow fadeInDown" data-wow-duration="2s" data-wow-delay="2s">holaa</span>
            <p class="textos wow fadeInLeft" data-wow-duration="2s" data-wow-delay="3s">lorem ipsum dolor sit adem operca</p>
            <p class="textos wow fadeInUp" data-wow-duration="2s" data-wow-delay="4s">dato 1</p>
            <p class="textos wow fadeInDown" data-wow-duration="2s" data-wow-delay="5s">dato 2</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/6768666-1080p-wallpapers.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="contenedor_carteleria_digital">
        <div class="contenedor_nombre_proyecto">
          <div class="nombre_proyecto_principal">
            <h2 class="textos wow fadeInUp" data-wow-duration="2s" data-wow-delay="0s">titulo</h2>
            <h5 class="textos wow fadeInDown" data-wow-duration="2s" data-wow-delay="1s">subtitulo</h5> <span class="textos wow fadeInDown" data-wow-duration="2s" data-wow-delay="2s">holaa</span>
            <p class="textos wow fadeInLeft" data-wow-duration="2s" data-wow-delay="3s">lorem ipsum dolor sit adem operca</p>
            <p class="textos wow fadeInUp" data-wow-duration="2s" data-wow-delay="4s">dato 1</p>
            <p class="textos wow fadeInDown" data-wow-duration="2s" data-wow-delay="5s">dato 2</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.hdbloggers.net/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/Wallpapers-HD-Picture.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="contenedor_carteleria_digital">
        <div class="contenedor_nombre_proyecto">
          <div class="nombre_proyecto_principal">
            <h2 class="textos wow fadeInUp" data-wow-duration="2s" data-wow-delay="0s">titulo</h2>
            <h5 class="textos wow fadeInDown" data-wow-duration="2s" data-wow-delay="1s">subtitulo</h5> <span class="textos wow fadeInDown" data-wow-duration="2s" data-wow-delay="2s">holaa</span>
            <p class="textos wow fadeInLeft" data-wow-duration="2s" data-wow-delay="3s">lorem ipsum dolor sit adem operca</p>
            <p class="textos wow fadeInUp" data-wow-duration="2s" data-wow-delay="4s">dato 1</p>
            <p class="textos wow fadeInDown" data-wow-duration="2s" data-wow-delay="5s">dato 2</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.hdbloggers.net/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/Wallpapers-HD-Picture.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="contenedor_carteleria_digital">
        <div class="contenedor_nombre_proyecto">
          <div class="nombre_proyecto_principal">
            <h2 class="textos wow fadeInUp" data-wow-duration="2s" data-wow-delay="0s">titulo</h2>
            <h5 class="textos wow fadeInDown" data-wow-duration="2s" data-wow-delay="1s">subtitulo</h5> <span class="textos wow fadeInDown" data-wow-duration="2s" data-wow-delay="2s">holaa</span>
            <p class="textos wow fadeInLeft" data-wow-duration="2s" data-wow-delay="3s">lorem ipsum dolor sit adem operca</p>
            <p class="textos wow fadeInUp" data-wow-duration="2s" data-wow-delay="4s">dato 1</p>
            <p class="textos wow fadeInDown" data-wow-duration="2s" data-wow-delay="5s">dato 2</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.hdbloggers.net/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/Wallpapers-HD-Picture.jpg">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--slideBox-->
</div>
```